# copy excel sheets with table references

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel 2007 document with multiple sheets, let's call it `source.xls`. I'd like to copy some of the sheets into all Excel documents within a folder, say `C:\some_folder`.

I figured how to loop over a directory:

```
Dim file As String
file = dir("C:\some_folder\*.xlsx")
Do While file <> ""

   Rem do_stuff

   file = dir()
Loop
```

And how to copy sheets between workbooks:

```
For Each ws in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = Workbook.Open(file)
    ws.Copy , wb.sheets(w.sheets.Count)
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Next ws
```

So far so good.

Now one of the sheets contains a table with external data from an SQL Server. Copying it works well.

Another sheet references data in that table as `Table_MYSERVER_MYDB[[row][col]]`. When I copy it, the references are automatically turned into `source.xls!Table_MYSERVER_MYDB[[row][col]]`

**UPDATE**:
I just tried to reference the data in the table by sheet and cell, e.g. `=Other_Sheet!A1`. Still the same problem, the reference magically turns into `=[source.xls]Other_Sheet!A1`.

**UPDATE 2**:
The next try was to access the cells in the other sheet with `=INDIRECT("Other_Sheet!"&CELL("address"))`, but that seems to trigger a bug in Excel 2007. All cells will show the same value. Try it for yourself :)

I'd like the sheets in the target document to reference the table in the same workbook. How would I do that?

I'm open for other solutions than VBA too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out myself:

My last desperate attempt was using Search&Replace over all formulas to remove [source.xls].

That's when a workmate suggested using:

```
wb.ChangeLink Name:=source.xls NewName:=wb.Name Type:=xlExcelLinks
```

Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyFormula()
Dim R1,R2 As Range

Set R1 = Workbooks("wb2.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A1")
Set R2 = Workbooks("wb1.xls").Sheets(1).Range("A1")

R1.Formula = R2.Formula
End Sub
```

Comment: While that might work, I'm afraid this will not scale well. I have to copy a thousands of cells in 10 sheets into a few thousand documents...

Comment: @chris Range could be anything ... ie "A1:Z99"

Comment: Ah, that might speed up things!